# Megamenu disappears after scroll using Foundation/Magellan

Tags: zurb-foundation, megamenu, magellan

We've used Foundation 5 and would like to use the sticky nav, Magellan. It's implemented here: http://www.whoi.edu/prototype/banner.html

At the top of the page, the dropdown hover works fine. The user can hover over the top nav, the megamenu appears and the user can click on anything within it. However, if the user scrolls down the page, and THEN tries to hover over the nav, the dropdown works, but the megamenu disappears once the user hovers over it. It seems to go off the top of the page.

I've tried adding:

> $(document).foundation('magellan-expedition', 'reflow');

and:

> $(document).foundation('dropdown', 'reflow');

I thought it might be a z-index issue or something else having to do with the page, but this problem seems to happen out of the Foundation box.

Any ideas as to how to stick the megamenu with the nav once the user has scrolled?